# Drag and Drop between separated component angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

This is my Directive to drag and drop

```
import {
Directive, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Input, Renderer
 } 
from '@angular/core';
import any = jasmine.any;
declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;

@Directive({
    selector: '[dnd]',
    host: {
        '(dragstart)': 'onDragStart($event)',
        '(dragend)': 'onDragEnd($event)',
        '(drag)': 'onDrag($event)',
        '(dragover)': 'onAllowDrop($event)',
        '(drop)': 'onDrop($event)',
        '(dragleave)': 'ondragleave($event)'
    }
})
export class dnd_drag {

    elementDrag:HTMLElement;
    elementDrop:HTMLElement;

    @Input("id_drag") id_drag;
    @Input("drop") drop;
    @Input("drag") drag;

    set setDrag(value:string) {
        this.id_drag = !!value;
    }

    set droppable(value:boolean) {
        this.drop = !!value;
    }

    elem:HTMLElement;

    constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {
        this.drop = false;
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'draggable', 'true');
    }

    onDrag(event:MouseEvent) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border-style', 'dotted');

    }

    onDragEnd(event:Event) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border', 'none');
    }

    onDragStart(event:DragEvent) {
        this.elementDrag = this.el.nativeElement;
        event.dataTransfer.setData('dnd', this.elementDrag.innerHTML);
    }

    onAllowDrop(event:DragEvent) {

        event.preventDefault();
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border', '4px dotted');
    }

    ondragleave(event:DragEvent) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border', 'none');
    }

    onDrop(event:DragEvent) {
        if (this.drop) {
            this.elementDrop = this.el.nativeElement;
            event.preventDefault();
            this.elementDrop.innerHTML += event.dataTransfer.getData('dnd');
            this.elementDrop.cloneNode(true);
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'border', 'none');
        }

    }
```

}

The component below is added dynamically after button click event in the parent component

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Dragula, DragulaService} from "ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula";
import {dnd_drag} from "../DND/dnd_drag";

@Component({
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"  >
              One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"  dnd [drop]="true">
              One of three columns
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"  dnd [drop]="true">
              One of three columns 
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>`,
    selector: 'div4-4-4',
    viewProviders: [DragulaService],
    directives: [Dragula,dnd_drag]

})

export class Div444 {

}
```

when I add my `div444` after button click I want to apply a drag and drop to the child component where I put `dnd [drop]="ture"`

this tag p I want to added it by drag and drop  `<p dnd>content of paragraph</p>`

The effect of drag and drop is working when drag over is work I mean it know that this div is for dragging but he don't add the content (I had already tried my Directive is working well)

what I noticed that function onDrop is not work it dont called when I do my drag&drop
Some know what is problem why don't add data after drag and drop thanks`

Comment: Maybe easier way is to use one of third party components. 
http://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html

Comment: in the directive dnd_drag the Input drop,
I noticed that he dont read the Input drop ,
when I removed the condition if (drop) it worked well